# What is the technology used in drum pads?

Tags: technology, technical

What's the underlying technology they use in drum pads to register the sound?

The thing that takes the kinetic input and creates the signal?

Like there is the pad itself that is just a shape made with rubber, but then somewhere in there there's a gadget that translates the force into an input whether digital or analog?

Would be great to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying sensor will be a piezo-electric pad which generates a voltage depending on the force presented to the pad. The generated voltage will then be converted to a midi note-on signal and an associated volume control level in the drum pads.

There are various online tutorials available that will show how these can be made using piezo-electric pads and arduino controllers.